# Accessing UUID from another class in Java

Tags: java

Here is the scenario:
I generate Random Data in one class and use it as an argument in a method in the same class.
How can i use the exact same value in another class ?

Here is a simplified version of my classes:

```
public class A {
    @Test
    public void aMethod() {     
        RandomStringUUID ruuid = new RandomStringUUID();
        }
}
```

Then:

```
public class B { 
        @Test
    public void bMethod() {
        // Want to use ruuid , without instantiating RandomStringUUID 
                // as i dont want new values, i want the one from class A
        }
}
```

Comment: What's the relationship between class A and some class B?

Comment: Tests should be reproduceable. You really shouldn't use random or other unpredicatable test data in your tests (data from production databases, dynamic ip addresses, etc). Imagine a test fails and you'll never know why just because each test run has different parameters..

Comment: @Andreas_D
In my case, its important to use random data, since this is part of a Test Framework, and since many people are using this against the SAME web service, hence uniqueness is a MUST

Comment: @Dynguss
I am not sure what you mean by relationship, as you can see that Class A and Class B are not extending one form another, or implementing any interface, there are simple classes, but sharing Data between them, Consider Class A as a Utility Class for Class B

Comment: @kamal "Consider Class A as a Utility Class for Class B" Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your variable a public static variable in class A

```
public static RandomStringUUID RUUID = new RandomStringUUID();
```

**After the beatdown I'm getting in the voting count**

```
private RandomStringUUID uuid;

private createUuid() {
    uuid = new RandomStringUUID();  //Or any other way you create it
}

public static RandomStringUUID getRuuidForOtherClassesToCheck() {
    return ruuid;
}
```

Not enough info on the OP's part to infer it's design rules or just a simple JAVA question on how to get a Variable from Class to Class.  :D

Comment: How are you certain that the functional requirement and technical design (which the OP didn't tell anything about) allows it being a class variable? Note that it's originally been created in an instance method. Making it a class variable may have unwanted side effects.

Comment: I hope you missed 'final' for this declaration. If not , then exchanging data via static variables is not something I would recommend to anyone. Unless you want to teach them bad programming habits.

Comment: @BalusC I don't and can't infer, looks to me like innocent JAVA straight up question

Comment: @gtgaxiola
Thanks , dont see why i would get -1 rating for this question, when there is already interest and learning for all of us. Seems unfair on part of stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

use a static approach:

```
public class A {

     private final static RandomStringUUID ruuid = new RandomStringUUID();

     public final static RandomStringUUID getRuuid() {
         return ruuid;
     }

     @Test
     public void aMethod() {     
         RandomStringUUID ruuid = getRuuid();
     }
}
```

and

```
public class B { 
    @Test
    public void bMethod() {
         RandomStringUUID ruuid = A.getRuuid();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either have A give the value to B

```
public class B {  
    @Test 
    public void bMethod(RandomStringUUID ruuid) { 
    // Want to use ruuid , without instantiating RandomStringUUID  
            // as i dont want new values, i want the one from class A 
    } 
}
```

Or have A make it available to be accessed by B, as @sics said

Answer (score 0):

We sometimes test use helper classes. That could be a solution for your (test) case. So `A` wouldn't provide the value to `B` but both would obtain the same object from a third class:

```
public class TestHelper {

  private final static RandomStringUUID UUID = new RandomStringUUID();

  public static RandomStringUUID getDummyRandomStringUUID() {
     return UUID;
  }
}
```

---

```
public class A {
  @Test
  public void aMethod() {     
    RandomStringUUID ruuid = TestHelper.getDummyRandomStringUUID();
  }
}
```

(and the same with `B`)

It's still questionable for testing, because each test run uses a different UUID value, so the tests are not reproduceable. It would be better to define a static UUID that is used for  every test run.